# How write solr query in PHP SOLR CLIENT

Tags: php, solr, solrj

I use apache solr 3.6, and php solr client. 
Now i do simple solr queries like 
`$query = 'url:"'.$searchSubject.'"';`
where `$searchSubject` is one word.
But I want to make some queries with two or more words.
I don't understand  how i must add some other parameters into code of PHP SOLR CLIENT.

Now i can add only query,  offset , limit .
`$response = $this->solr->search($query, $offset = 0, $limit = 10000);`

Answer (score 2):

You can just insert multiple words into the parameter $query using the format specified in [lucene query parser syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html)

$query = 'url:"' . $searchSubject . '"';

if you would like to search for two urls, the query can be

$query = 'url:("' . $searchSubject1 . '" OR "' . $searchSubject2 . '")';

Answer (score 0):

In solr you can simply create query for multiple words.

```
$query = url:"($searchSubject1 $searchSubject2 $searchSubject3)";
```

space between $searchSubject1 and $searchSubject2 will take default OR condition.